# glassfish v3 Validation Error: Value is not valid

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

i am developing app on jsf2.1 and primefaces 3.5, i have switched my application from tomcat-7.0.39 to glassfish-3.1.2.2-web
it was working fine on tomcat but in GF v3 i ve got ERROR
`baaaffId_tabview:appropriateId_form:formationAppropriateId_select: Validation Error: Value is not valid` i ve seen this question in many blogs n forum but didnot understand answer can anyone clear it?

**here is my code:**

```
<p:tabView id="baaaffId_tabview" style="width:100%;">
<p:tab title="Appropriate Budget" id="appropriateId_tab">
<h:form id="appropriateId_form">
<h:selectOneMenu id="formationAppropriateId_select" value="{generalInformationAction.budgetFormationsBean.budgetFormationIdBean}" required="true"
requiredMessage="Select any formation">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="formation" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{generalInformationAction.budgetFormationsBean.budgetFormationMapBean}" />
<f:ajax event="change" render=":#{p:component('appropriateId_datatable')}" listener="#{budgetAppropriateOrAdditionalFormationWiseAction.getFormationBudgetForAppropriate}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
/// closing tags
```

**BudgetAppropriateOrAdditionalFormationWiseAction**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BudgetAppropriateOrAdditionalFormationWiseAction implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{budgetFormationsBean}")
    private BudgetFormationsBean budgetFormationsBean;

}
```

i have checked above class using `viewScoped`

**BudgetFormationsBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="budgetFormationsBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BudgetFormationsBean implements Serializable {
// some other beans
private Map<String , Integer> budgetFormationMapBean = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
//setter and getter
}
```

again i am running this app on `tomcat` its working fine for me

Comment: First of all why are u using h:selectOneMenu instead of p:SelectOneMenu.??

Comment: just because i dont like theme of `p:SelectOneMenu` `h:` has simple HTML theme

Comment: see my question clearly app was working fine on tomcat